# PySpark streaming issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I will receive events from the Eventhb continuously
1.First if the userid is not available in the final table means then I have to register that data into the table
2.implement the aggregation on streaming dataframe
3.need to join the aggregation data frame with the final dataframe then update the matching records

Here the reason is to join aggregation datframe with final dataframe for ex if the address is available in final dataframe and not available in static dataframe means taking data from static dataframe

Finally update will happen..
But I am facing concurrent update issue..

Please help me with solution